# How to label different plots on one graph

Tags: mathematica, wolfram-alpha

[I need to sign each plot separately, but I don’t know how to do it. PlotLabel signs all of them above the y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQPQe.png)

Comment: I am sorry that I added a picture in the form of a hyperlink, I understand that it can be inconvenient, just so far I have poorly understood the interface of the site

Comment: Are you just looking for [PlotLegends](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) or for callouts like `Plot[{Callout[Sin[x], "sin[x]]"], Callout[Cos[x], "cos[x]"]}, {x, 0, 
  10}]`?

Comment: @Alan Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!!!